# How to find out what font family is used by a paragraph in OOXML?

Tags: fonts, ms-word, apache-poi, docx, xwpf

Lets say that a particular style is applied to a paragraph. I want to find out what the font family of the style is. I tried opening `styles.xml` file inside the docx. I cannot find the `w:ascii` attribute set for a lot of the styles. For example, consider the style `Heading1`. The OOXML corresponding to this style is

```
<w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Heading1">
    <w:name w:val="heading 1"/>
    <w:basedOn w:val="Normal"/>
    <w:next w:val="Normal"/>
    <w:link w:val="Heading1Char"/>
    <w:uiPriority w:val="9"/>
    <w:qFormat/>
    <w:rsid w:val="00FB3E81"/>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:keepNext/>
        <w:keepLines/>
        <w:spacing w:before="240"/>
        <w:outlineLvl w:val="0"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="majorHAnsi" w:eastAsiaTheme="majorEastAsia" w:hAnsiTheme="majorHAnsi" w:cstheme="majorBidi"/>
        <w:color w:val="2E74B5" w:themeColor="accent1" w:themeShade="BF"/>
        <w:sz w:val="32"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="32"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:style>
```

In the `w:rFonts` tag there is no `w:ascii` attribute to extract the font family. Where is the font family details for this style is stored and how to extract it for use in a java application? I am using Apache POI for parsing the document.

Comment: This is what I am doing right now. Go up the hierarchy till there is no more `w:basedOn` and then if I still haven't found the font, I am setting a default font manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examine `w:rFonts`. In the example you cite `w:asciiTheme="majorHAnsi"` tells you that it is using the font which has been defined in the theme as `majorHAnsi` , which is the theme font used for headings. So you would need to determine the font family specified in the theme file, which is likely to be theme1.xml

**Edit:**
In the theme file you will find the fontScheme which defines two fonts, `majorFont` and `minorFont`. These correspond to `majorHAnsi` and `minorHAnsi` If the theme being used is one of the standard themes that come with Office there may be numerous entries dependent on the language script being used.

```
        <a:fontScheme name="Office Theme">
        <a:majorFont>
            <a:latin typeface="Calibri Light" panose="020F0302020204030204" />
            <a:ea typeface="" />
            <a:cs typeface="" />
            <a:font script="Jpan" typeface="游ゴシック Light" />
            <a:font script="Hang" typeface="맑은 고딕" />
            <a:font script="Hans" typeface="等线 Light" />
            <a:font script="Hant" typeface="新細明體" />
            <a:font script="Arab" typeface="Times New Roman" />
            <a:font script="Hebr" typeface="Times New Roman" />
            <a:font script="Thai" typeface="Angsana New" />
            <a:font script="Ethi" typeface="Nyala" />
            <a:font script="Beng" typeface="Vrinda" />
            <a:font script="Gujr" typeface="Shruti" />
            <a:font script="Khmr" typeface="MoolBoran" />
            <a:font script="Knda" typeface="Tunga" />
            <a:font script="Guru" typeface="Raavi" />
            <a:font script="Cans" typeface="Euphemia" />
            <a:font script="Cher" typeface="Plantagenet Cherokee" />
            <a:font script="Yiii" typeface="Microsoft Yi Baiti" />
            <a:font script="Tibt" typeface="Microsoft Himalaya" />
            <a:font script="Thaa" typeface="MV Boli" />
            <a:font script="Deva" typeface="Mangal" />
            <a:font script="Telu" typeface="Gautami" />
            <a:font script="Taml" typeface="Latha" />
            <a:font script="Syrc" typeface="Estrangelo Edessa" />
            <a:font script="Orya" typeface="Kalinga" />
            <a:font script="Mlym" typeface="Kartika" />
            <a:font script="Laoo" typeface="DokChampa" />
            <a:font script="Sinh" typeface="Iskoola Pota" />
            <a:font script="Mong" typeface="Mongolian Baiti" />
            <a:font script="Viet" typeface="Times New Roman" />
            <a:font script="Uigh" typeface="Microsoft Uighur" />
            <a:font script="Geor" typeface="Sylfaen" />
        </a:majorFont>
        <a:minorFont>
            <a:latin typeface="Calibri" panose="020F0502020204030204" />
            <a:ea typeface="" />
            <a:cs typeface="" />
            <a:font script="Jpan" typeface="游ゴシック" />
            <a:font script="Hang" typeface="맑은 고딕" />
            <a:font script="Hans" typeface="等线" />
            <a:font script="Hant" typeface="新細明體" />
            <a:font script="Arab" typeface="Arial" />
            <a:font script="Hebr" typeface="Arial" />
            <a:font script="Thai" typeface="Cordia New" />
            <a:font script="Ethi" typeface="Nyala" />
            <a:font script="Beng" typeface="Vrinda" />
            <a:font script="Gujr" typeface="Shruti" />
            <a:font script="Khmr" typeface="DaunPenh" />
            <a:font script="Knda" typeface="Tunga" />
            <a:font script="Guru" typeface="Raavi" />
            <a:font script="Cans" typeface="Euphemia" />
            <a:font script="Cher" typeface="Plantagenet Cherokee" />
            <a:font script="Yiii" typeface="Microsoft Yi Baiti" />
            <a:font script="Tibt" typeface="Microsoft Himalaya" />
            <a:font script="Thaa" typeface="MV Boli" />
            <a:font script="Deva" typeface="Mangal" />
            <a:font script="Telu" typeface="Gautami" />
            <a:font script="Taml" typeface="Latha" />
            <a:font script="Syrc" typeface="Estrangelo Edessa" />
            <a:font script="Orya" typeface="Kalinga" />
            <a:font script="Mlym" typeface="Kartika" />
            <a:font script="Laoo" typeface="DokChampa" />
            <a:font script="Sinh" typeface="Iskoola Pota" />
            <a:font script="Mong" typeface="Mongolian Baiti" />
            <a:font script="Viet" typeface="Arial" />
            <a:font script="Uigh" typeface="Microsoft Uighur" />
            <a:font script="Geor" typeface="Sylfaen" />
        </a:minorFont>
    </a:fontScheme>
```

Comment: This works for the themes that come with office. But there is no way to get third party themes.

Comment: No, it works for user themes too, in which case there will be less data in the theme. If the theme has been overridden the font data will be in the style. If the style data has been overridden the font data will be held with the paragraph in the document. I suggest you spend some time getting familiar with the xml for a document.

Comment: I got it. I found out what i wanted. Now, how do I read this theme1.xml file using Apache POI ? I tried looking at the methods in XWPFDocument and i couldn't find anything

Comment: That is something that I can't help you with. I suggest that you create another question asking for the specific help that you need.